# Multiline label in stackview in cell

Tags: ios, label, tableview, multiline, stackview

I have been struggling for more than two hours with this problem : how to get my cell to grow according to my label embedded in a stack view

[image]

As you can see I have a fully constrained horizontal UIStackView. Inside I have a vertical UIStackView. My problem is with the title label. I cant get it to be more than one line. I tried everything: adding constraints, playing with stack view parameters, changing content hugging and compression...

Of course I have:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And my title label has a line number of 0.

So if you guys have a solution to this problem it would be very helpful, thank you !

Comment: Found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386528/multiline-label-in-uistackview